# Media element "mediaPlayer_MediaEnded" not firing end of the voice

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-media-player

I just try to play vocie file using wpf mediaPlayer. here is sample code that i used. but mediaPlayer.MediaEnded += mediaPlayer_MediaEnded event not firing end of the voice.

```
private void PlayVoice(string voiceFileURL)
{
    try
    {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.MediaEnded += mediaPlayer_MediaEnded;
        mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(voiceFileURL.Replace("https://","http://")));

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                mediaPlayer.Play();
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }                       
        } 
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {  
    }
    finally
    {   
    }
}

void mediaPlayer_MediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    mediaPlayer.Stop(); 
}
```

Comment: Looking at `void mediaPlayer_MediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs e) { }`, I'm assuming your `mediaPlayer_MediaEnded()` method is indeed not empty as the question shows. Could we see part / all off the actual code? This is because your syntax seems to be correct.

Comment: Did you register `mediaPlayer_MediaEnded` to the event? That's not clear from your current code snippet, and could explain your problem.

Comment: here you see the complete code at https://pastebin.com/kkRPag3S

Comment: when the form load, end of the voice mediaPlayer_MediaEnded evet not fire. but when i play it after loaded mediaPlayer_MediaEnded evet fire.why it's happen.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try
`LoadedBehavior = Manual` also `UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Stop`
As [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.loadedbehavior.aspx) states

> LoadedBehavior must be set to Manual in order to interactively control media with the Play, Pause, and Stop methods

Comment: are there any way to stop  soundPlayer.PlaySync() SoundPlayer. I need to stop play while it running.

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905192/soundplayer-stop-does-not-stop-sound-playback), this might suffice what you are looking for about `SoundPlayer`. And btw did my solution help you with your actual question. If yes then click the tick on the left to accept it